# Playing audio on touchstart

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get a sound to play when a touchstart function is initiated on JQuery mobile. How would I go about doing this? The code below does not play the audio element in a mobile browser but works fine on a desktop browser. Thanks a ton!

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'DING.mp3');

$("#LNum").bind("touchstart", function() {
     audioElement.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to add src attribute in `<audio>` tag instead of `<source>`.

```
 <audio controls>
  <source src="ding.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="ding.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
 </audio>
```

you need to create a `source` element inside your `audioElement`.
and then apply `src` attribute to source tag.

I use following solution

**HTML**

```
 <audio class="my_audio" controls preload="none" style="display: none" id="audioControl">
    <source class="notificationTone" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

**JS**

```
$("#LNum").bind("touchstart click tap", function() {
    $(".notificationTone").attr('src', "somemp3.mp3");
    $(".my_audio").trigger('load');
    $(".my_audio").trigger('play');    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling it wasn't formatted correctly.